# kendo grid column: how to data bind click event in footer template?

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

Kendo Grid columns' data-bind click event in the footer template is not working.

Please see the example http://dojo.telerik.com/ALAZo

The click event on  column template for price is working fine but not for the footer template for the same.

Any resolution which uses MVVM binding would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the header and footer of the Grid are not bound to the ViewModel. A workaround is to find the footer with an appropriate jquery selector after the grid has been initialised and then bind it manually. So something like this:

```
kendo.bind($("body"), viewModel);
kendo.bind($("#grid").find(".k-grid-footer"), viewModel);
```

Here I've added id="grid" to your grid declaration like so in order to find it:

```
<div id="grid" data-role="grid" data-bind="source:dataSource"
```

Comment: kendo.bind to the the footer element will resolve this issue. 
Is there any way we can change the default behavior that the header and footer of the Grid are not bound to the ViewModel so that we could avoid the binding explicitly.

Comment: Unfortunately not at this time. There are no configuration options on the grid to do this automatically, although Telerik may change this in a future release if they receive enough requests (you can request new features for future releases if you have a Kendo UI license).

Comment: I see, I will place a request.

Marking this as the answer since rebind will do. I am (re)binding the view model to one of the element in the footer column in the databound event of the grid so that it will be triggered each time when there is change in the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I have [reworked your example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ALAZo/6) in order to get a solution where click event works on both column and footer template.

`<a onclick='test()'...` seems to do the trick.

Comment: the MVVM binding is missing in this approach. so its not an acceptable solution :(.

Comment: Well I didn't see that specified anywhere in the OP... _"any resolution would be greatly appreciated"_ should probably be changed to _"any resolution which uses MVVM binding would be greatly appreciated"_ ;)